# 80's/90's novel about a post-apocalyptic gunman, NOT GUNSLINGER, ending with the first atomic bomb test?

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic, western

First up, this is NOT *Gunslinger* by Stephen King. I read this in the 90's, but it could have been from the 80's.

It was about a cowboy type guy in a post-apocalyptic future who made his own bullets for his six-shooter, and I remember distinctly that it ended with him killing the main bad guy (a demon or alien or something) by sending him back to ground zero of the first atomic bomb detonation.

Could have been a trilogy, but the thing I remember the most was the ending and him melting down lead to make bullets and reusing his shell casings. Been trying to find it again for years!!

Comment: Sci Fi westerns... There are a few. Sounds possibly like Mike Resnick's Santiago (1986). https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/293291.Santiago?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=addz6ozBEb&rank=1

Comment: If the postapocalyptic cowboy has a time machine, why doesn't he go back to the past to buy ammo?

Comment: Lol good point, but it made sense in the novel. It wasn't Santiago, but thank you! It all took place on earth, no outer space stuff.

Comment: @user14111 Obviously because the time machine is uni-directional.  Because the past exists, you can target a time and location.  But the future doesn't exist yet, you can't bring goods into the future because you don't know where to send them (yet).  At least that's what my temporal mechanics professor said, or will say - English is not a good language for describing temporal travel concepts.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is David Gemmell's "Bloodstone", the third of his Jon Shannow novels. Published 1995 so fits with your timeframe.

Your memory is correct in that Shannow was a "cowboy type guy in a post-apocalyptic future who made his own bullets".

The novel ends with the Big Bad being transported by Shannow, at the Big Bad's request, to the 20th century where he could feast on billions of souls. Unfortunately, he left it up to Shannow to decide where/when he would end up. A classic evil overlord mistake.

> I can't die! I can't die!
>
> He was one hundred and seventy-seven yards from the tower at 5:30am on July 16 1945. One second later the tower was vaporized. For hundreds of yards around the zero point, that Oppenheimer had christened ***Trinity***, the desert sand was fused to glass. The ball of incandescent air formed by the explosion rose rapidly to a height of 35,000 feet.
>
> Several miles away, J. Robert Oppenheimer watched the mushroom cloud form. All around him men began cheering. "Today I am become death", he said.

Comment: FYI the location of the Trinity site is open to the public twice a year (here are the [2022](https://www.wsmr.army.mil/fn/Pages/2022-Trinity-Site-Open-House-Dates.aspx) dates)

Comment: That's a great ending.