# Story involving time travel that ends with the villain being destroyed by the Trinity nuclear test

Tags: story-identification

The title is basically all I remember from the story. For some reason the Big Bad could not be destroyed/defeated by conventional means, so one of the good guys tricked him into time-travelling to the Trinity nuclear test site just before the Gadget was detonated.

Comment: [Bloodstone by David Gemmell](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/526067.Bloodstone). Asked about only a moth ago in [80's/90's novel about a post-apocalyptic gunman, NOT GUNSLINGER, ending with the first atomic bomb test?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269799/80s-90s-novel-about-a-post-apocalyptic-gunman-not-gunslinger-ending-with-the)

Comment: Let us know if it is the same story and we'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yup, that's it, thank you! Stack Exchange search didn't pick it up because Stack Exchange search is doo-doo.